# count rows in foreach based on value

Tags: php, foreach, cakephp-1.2

Good day all,
I need help in [project table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47yul.png)
I have a table called projects and i want to count the projects based on country_id column using php in a foreach... ist possible?
however i am using cakephp the old version 1.2 ...

I tried this code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Country </th>
        <th>Country Name</th>
        <th>Number of Place</th>
    </tr>

    <?php 
    $count_country =0;
    $country_count_each=0;
    foreach ($projects as $project){ 
        $country_count_each = $project['Project']['country_id'];
        if($project['Project']['country_id']==$country_count_each){
            $count_country+=$country_count_each;
    
?>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 30%"><?php echo $project['Project']['country_id']; ?></td>
        <td style="width: 30%"><?php echo 'Country Name'.$tt; ?></td>
        <td style="width: 30%"><?php echo $count_country; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
        } 
    }
    ?>

</table>
```

[image: Project Table]

Comment: Why don't you do the counting in the SQL query? `SELECT country_id, COUNT(*) FROM project GROUP BY country`?

Comment: i am new in this and using cakephp, so i do not know where do add the SQL statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the entire array and get all the counts first. You can put them into an associative array:

```
$country_counts = [];
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $country = $project['Project']['country_id'];
    if (isset($country_counts[$country])) {
        $country_counts[$country]++;
    } else {
        $country_counts[$country] = 1;
    }
}

?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Country </th>
        <th>Country Name</th>
        <th>Number of Place</th>
    </tr>

    <?php 
    foreach ($projects as $project) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 30%"><?php echo $project['Project']['country_id']; ?></td>
            <td style="width: 30%"><?php echo 'Country Name'.$tt; ?></td>
            <td style="width: 30%"><?php echo $country_counts[$project['Project']['country_id']]; ?></td>
        </tr>  
    <?php 
    } 
?>

</table>
```

Comment: one more question can it be managed to send this value the resualt as well to another index which is related to other controller.  From projects/index  to countries/index

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can save the results in a session variable and use it in another page.